# mysql-server crashing periodically

Tags: mysql

I am running a drupal instance on an ubuntu server. However, it seems that the mysql server tends to crash periodically.

The log I am fetching is this:

```
131221  4:22:54 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

131221  4:22:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131221  4:22:55 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131221  4:22:55 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131221  4:22:55 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
131221  4:22:55 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
131221  4:22:55 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131221  4:22:55 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
131221  4:22:55 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
131221  4:22:55 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
131221  4:22:55 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
131221  4:22:55 [ERROR] Aborting

131221  4:22:55 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

131223  8:22:00 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131223  8:22:00 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131223  8:22:00 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131223  8:22:00 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
131223  8:22:00 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131223  8:22:00 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131223  8:22:00 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 4844461078
131223  8:22:00  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
```

Do you have any suggestions of how this can be resolved? I tried to play around with various numbers in my.cnf but I no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/562453/why-is-apache-running-wild-and-killing-mysql/ ...the log does not indicate a crash, it's a refusal to start due to insufficient free memory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your system doesn't have sufficient spare memory for the innodb buffer pool. You could try reducing the size of innodb_buffer_pool in the my.cnf file

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10M
```

for example, then restart mysql. Reducing the innodb buffer pool size may impact the performance of your system so you'll need to be aware of this and perhaps consider some other tuning too.